# Microsoft Access 2003 on Windows 7 x64 fails to restart after loading a form that has a subform

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2003

Here's the problem:

Open Access 2003 on Windows 7 and load a form that has a subform. Then close Access. Try to start it again. You can't. You click on the start menu to run it but nothing happens.

But if you start it and load a form that does not have a subform, then you can close and restart it just fine.

Then I noticed that even though I had closed it there was an Access process still running.

So this clue provided my best workaround so far.  I wrote a short batch file that I call 'Kill all MSAccess.bat' that is just this one line `Taskkill /IM "MSACCESS.EXE" /f`.  I put it in `C:/Program Files (x86)/` and created a short cut to it in my programs list.

When Access won't start, or if I know that I've just run an Access form that will hang it, I click on this task just before starting Access.

**I'd really like to find a better solution rather than this workaround**, if anyone knows of one???

---

(FTY, if you're wondering why I haven't upgraded...  I am still using Access 2003 because it works so nicely. I bought Access 2007 a few years ago to upgrade it, but found that I just like the menus in Access 2003 so much better. I sort of thought MS screwed up 2007, and didn't add enough new features to make it worth the new mess.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed all of the latest service packs and updates for the version you have. I know they are going to be gone by April 2014 as this is EOL for Office 2003. You might also run through the Office Repair tool to fix anything that may be missing or corrupt in the Access file base.

Comment: Yes, thanks I do generally keep my system up to date.  And yes I know that Office 2003's days are limited, I guess aren't we all limited.  I tried fully re-installing but that didn't fix it.  Thanks